# How do I tell Google that I prefer Python3 results?

Tags: google-search

Google is supposed to learn what results I want. However, it *continually* produces the Python 2 documentation when I'm searching. Obviously it's only another click or two, or I could type "3" in my search... but I'd really just like to be able to search for `python <term>` and get links to version 3 docs.

Other than just searching and looking for the 3 docs and clicking on that like crazy to try and build up a search bubble, is there any way to just tell Google, "Hey, unless I add '2' to my string, I really don't care about those docs?"

Comment: ...good question!